# Paid keyword reports not displaying any graphs

Tags: experience-analytics, reporting

In the `Experience Analytics`, none of the `Paid Keyword` reports are showing any graphs for our site. All the reports show - **"No data to display"**.

e.g:

> Aquisition - Keywords - Top paid keywords   Aquisition - Keywords -
>   Paid overview - Google - Top keywords by visits   Aquisition -
>   Keywords - Paid overview - Bing - Top keywords by visits   Aquisition
>   - Keywords - Paid overview - Facebook - Top keywords by visits

In CMS, there is an option to set [branded keywords](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/analyzing_and_reporting/analytics/configuring/set_up_branded_keywords). Is there any similar setting or configuration to be done to get these reports working.

Using Sitecore 8.2 update 5

Answer (score 2):

To identify paid traffic,

1. Create a campaign item
2. Set the 'Channel' field to the appropriate the appropriate channel type. Using Google as an example, you would set the channel to 'Online/Paid search/Google ads'
3. Get the query string from the 'Campaign link' field, ex sc_camp=B51BDDEE334E4E33976743398F48F227
4. Add the query string to the paid advertisement link, ex http:///?sc_camp=B51BDDEE334E4E33976743398F48F227
5. Go to the item that that corresponds with the URL of the paid advertisement and add the campaign to that item by selecting the 'ANALYZE' tab in the Content Editor ribbon
6. Click on the Attributes icon in the 'Attributes' section to open the 'Attributes' dialog
7. Ensure that you are in the 'CAMPAIGNS' tab of the 'Attributes' dialog and click the checkbox of the corresponding campaign
8. Click 'OK' and save the item
9. Publish the changes

If the paid channel provides keywords, the keywords are parsed from the HTTP Referer header that it sent with the request. For example, an HTTP Referer header from a Bing request:
Referer: http://www.bing.com/search?q=keyword&go=Search&qs=n&form=QBRE&pq=sitecore&sc=8-8&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=3D6EAC2F09594E2BB526D2B3A2A48EA4

Google no longer supports keywords in the HTTP Referrer header as part of their security updates.